# Office 365 REST API: Correct for daylight savings time

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, dst, office365-restapi

The [Office 365 REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog) returns local dates and times with time zones. As the documentation explains, time zones are specified by strings from [this standard Windows list of zones](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749073(v=ws.10).aspx). Here's an example of a date/time value returned by the API, in JSON:

```
{ DateTime: '2016-04-13T08:00:00.0000000',
  TimeZone: 'Pacific Standard Time' }
```

Let's say you want to use this date---for example, to parse it to a JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. You might think that, to parse this date, you'd just need to look up that time zone name in a table to get its offset.

But that's not quite right! Because that date is in April, it's actually specified in daylight time: the appointment it reflects is at 8 AM **PDT**, not PST, despite all appearances. The date contains no indication of daylight savings time, and "Pacific Daylight Time" isn't even a valid time zone according to [that list](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749073(v=ws.10).aspx).

Does the API provide any facilities for getting the real, daylight-sensitive time zone offset for one of these values? Or am I on my own to compensate for DST in my JavaScript client?

Comment: try moment.js, it should be helpful on this one:http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 0):

Pacific Daylight Time / Pacific Daylight Saving Time are not Time zone (time zone is geography based). The TimeZone property in Office 365 REST API can be set to any of the time zones supported by Windows, as well as the following time zones names.

```
Etc/GMT+12

Etc/GMT+11

Pacific/Honolulu

America/Anchorage

America/Santa_Isabel

America/Los_Angeles

America/Phoenix

America/Chihuahua

America/Denver

America/Guatemala

America/Chicago

America/Mexico_City

America/Regina

America/Bogota

America/New_York

America/Indiana/Indianapolis

America/Caracas

America/Asuncion

America/Halifax

America/Cuiaba

America/La_Paz

America/Santiago

America/St_Johns

America/Sao_Paulo

America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires

America/Cayenne

America/Godthab

America/Montevideo

America/Bahia

Etc/GMT+2

Atlantic/Azores

Atlantic/Cape_Verde

Africa/Casablanca

Etc/GMT

Europe/London

Atlantic/Reykjavik

Europe/Berlin

Europe/Budapest

Europe/Paris

Europe/Warsaw

Africa/Lagos

Africa/Windhoek

Europe/Bucharest

Asia/Beirut

Africa/Cairo

Asia/Damascus

Africa/Johannesburg

Europe/Kiev

Europe/Istanbul

Asia/Jerusalem

Asia/Amman

Asia/Baghdad

Europe/Kaliningrad

Asia/Riyadh

Africa/Nairobi

Asia/Tehran

Asia/Dubai

Asia/Baku

Europe/Moscow

Indian/Mauritius

Asia/Tbilisi

Asia/Yerevan

Asia/Kabul

Asia/Karachi

Asia/Tashkent

Asia/Kolkata

Asia/Colombo

Asia/Kathmandu

Asia/Almaty

Asia/Dhaka

Asia/Yekaterinburg

Asia/Rangoon

Asia/Bangkok

Asia/Novosibirsk

Asia/Shanghai

Asia/Krasnoyarsk

Asia/Singapore

Australia/Perth

Asia/Taipei

Asia/Ulaanbaatar

Asia/Irkutsk

Asia/Tokyo

Asia/Seoul

Australia/Adelaide

Australia/Darwin

Australia/Brisbane

Australia/Sydney

Pacific/Port_Moresby

Australia/Hobart

Asia/Yakutsk

Pacific/Guadalcanal

Asia/Vladivostok

Pacific/Auckland

Etc/GMT-12

Pacific/Fiji

Asia/Magadan

Pacific/Tongatapu

Pacific/Apia

Pacific/Kiritimati
```

In this case, the app need to handle it itself which means that you need to compensate for DST in his JavaScript client.